# Div not wrapping around child content

Tags: css

my black background in my form-section div isn't wrapping around the content. I've tried inline-block but it's still taking up the whole screen.. I'm trying to wrap the transparent one around text and form. If anyone could help that would be so appreciated :)`

```css
@import "elements.less";
@import "normalize.less";
@import "var.less";
@import "background.less";

    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
.cb-slideshow {
 list-style-type: none;
} 
body {
.font();
color: #fff;

}
header img {
 margin: 0 auto;
 display: block;
 margin-top: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
h2 { 
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
.font( 30px, normal);
line-height: 38px;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
html,body
{
  height: 100%;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
}

.grid {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.left {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}
.right {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
}


p.xlarge {
    font-size: 72px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1;
    }
p.large {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-family: 'bariol_light';
    line-height: 1;
    a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color:#fff;
    }
      a:hover {
        color:#3399FF;
       }
    }
  
.form-section {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    border-radius: 2%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
section p {
 .font(20px);
 text-align: center;
}
section > p {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.contact-info {
 margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
 width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}

form {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 25px 5px 25px;
}

label {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
}
label .label-text {
  cursor: text;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-34px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-34px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-34px);
  transform: translateY(-34px);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
label input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #4A4A4A;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  width: 300px;
  color: #fff;
}
label input:focus {
  width: 400px;
}
label input:focus + .label-text {
  color: #F0F0F0;
  font-size: 13px;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-74px);
  transform: translateY(-74px);
}
label input:valid + .label-text {
  font-size: 13px;
  -moz-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-74px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-74px);
  transform: translateY(-74px);
    color: #fff;
}
textarea {
            height: 120px;
            width: 300px;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-size: 20px;
            line-height: 2em;
            border-radius: 2%;
            background-color:rgba(200,200,200, 0.6);
         transition: height .3s ease-out;
            transition: width .3s ease-out;
        }
        textarea:focus {
            border: 2px solid #3399FF;
            height: 200px;
            width: 400px;
            transition: height .3s ease-out;
            transition: width .3s ease-out;
        }

button {
  background-color: #333333;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 27px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: all 200ms;
}
button:hover, button:focus {
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color .6s ease-out;
  color: #333333;
  outline: 0;
}

ul.share-buttons{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.share-buttons li{
  display: inline;
}

.band {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #c7efef;
    height: 6px;
    float: left;
}
.strip {
    float: left;
    height: 6px;
}
.blue2 {
    background-color: #4894b0;
    width: 23.828125%;
}
.teal2 {
    background-color: #6bc8c8;
    width: 11.640625%;
}
.sand { 
    width: 19.296875%;
    background-color: #f3c281;
}
.salmon {
    width: 16.015625%;
    background-color: #e64564;
}
footer {
 padding: 10px;
background-color: #262F36;
 p {
    color: #fff;
}
.cta {
 font-size: 24px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
input.submit-button {
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            float: left;
            background-color: #0066FF;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    
}


.slideshow {
 list-style-type: none;
}
.container{
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}


.slideshow,
.slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 160px;
    padding: 0 30px;
    line-height: 120px;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(1) span { background-image: url(http://www.webreality.co.uk/media/15625/wr-team-slider2.png) }
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(http://www.webreality.co.uk/media/15583/bellmans-1.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(http://www.webreality.co.uk/media/1102/crestbridge.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(http://www.webreality.co.uk/media/1055/tlc-home.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url(http://www.webreality.co.uk/media/15644/zuri_ipad.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url(http://www.webreality.co.uk/media/1059/umbraco-slider-3.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
     -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 22% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-20%);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-100%);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.05);
     -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 22% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-20%);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-100%);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -o-transform: scale(1.05);
     -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -o-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 22% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-20%);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-100%);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
     -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 22% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-20%);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -ms-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-100%);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     animation-timing-function: ease-in;
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1.05);
     animation-timing-function: ease-out;
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: scale(1.1);
 }
 22% {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-20%);
 }
 25% {
     opacity: 0;
     -transform: scale(1.1) translateY(-100%);
 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-300%);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform: translateY(-300%);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -moz-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform: translateY(-300%);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -o-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -o-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     -o-transform: translateY(100%);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     -ms-transform: translateY(-300%);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     -ms-transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation { 
 0% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translateY(-300%);
 }
 8% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 17% {
     opacity: 1;
     transform: translateY(0%);
 }
 19% {
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translateY(100%);
 }
 25% { opacity: 0 }
 100% { opacity: 0 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9"><![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title> WebReality Holding Page</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul class="slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 05</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 06</span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="container">
    <header>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/60tFZ1e.png" alt="logo"/>
    </header>
    <div class="form-section"
    <section class="pw">
        <!-- @import "/Partials/header.html" -->
        <div class="contact-info">
            <h2> We're here to help </h2>
            <p> We help people plan, design, build and market their web and mobile projects. </p>
            <div class="grid">
            <div class="plan left">
            <h3> Plan </h3> <p>
            Wondering where to start? Let us draw you a map! Our wide experience means we usually have directly relevant insights when it comes to strategic planning. </p>
            </div>
<div class="design right">
<h3> Design </h3>
<p> Design for digital media is a fast-changing specialist field. In the world of design, digital is all we do. Websites, apps, email marketing, branding, mobile vouchers... We make it beautiful. </p>
</div>

<div class="build left">
<h3> Build </h3>
<p> At heart, we're a technology business. We have deep skills in software development for web and mobile. Whether it's building what we designed, or working with your design partner, we can help. </p>
</div>
<div class="market right">
<h3>Market</h3>
<p>Plan it, design it, build it... now you need to feed it and get it seen.</p>
</div>
</div>
        </div>
            <form>
                <label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                    <div class="label-text">Name</div>
                  </label>
                  <label>
                    <input type="text" required />
                    <div class="label-text">Email</div>
                  </label>
                <label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
                <div class="textbox">
                <textarea name="Message" rows="20" cols="20" id="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                  <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
            
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    </section>
    </div>
<div class="band">
    <div class="strip blue2"></div>
    <div class="strip teal2"></div>
    <div class="strip sand"></div>
    <div class="strip salmon"></div>
    <div class="strip blue3"></div>
</div>

    <footer class="fw">
    <div class="cta pw">
        <p class="xlarge">Get in touch</p>
        <p class="large"><span>01534 488888</span> or <a href="mailto:info@webreality.co.uk">email us »</a></p>
    <p><span>2 La Chasse</span>, <span >St Helier</span> <span>JE2 4UE</span></p>
</div>
<ul class="share-buttons">
  <li><a href="#" title="Share on Facebook" target="_blank"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/7kQQwLU.png" alt="Facebook Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Tweet"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/zEUBZSI.png" alt="Twitter Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/hNgPsyc.png" alt="Google+ Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Post to Tumblr"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vnwhljt.png" alt="Tumblr Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Pin it"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/8g0gxyZ.png" alt="Pin it Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Add to Pocket"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/rTqXncE.png" alt="Pocket Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Submit to Reddit"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ehb3wbL.png" alt="Reddit Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Share on LinkedIn"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/tujqxUY.png" alt="LinkedIn Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Publish on WordPress"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/EXy9FOK.png" alt="WordPress Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Save to Pinboard"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/4qhISPT.png" alt="Pinboard Share"></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" target="_blank" title="Email"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ZEAJvU5.png" alt="Email"></a></li>
</ul>
    </footer>
    </body>
        <!-- @import "/Partials/footer.html" -->
        <!-- @import "/Partials/additional-code.html" -->
    </body>
</html>
```

`

Comment: Can you produce a **minimal** demo of the issue. It looks like your dumped the whole kitchen sink in the code you have provided.

Comment: tried to find it, no success, but here's a minimal jsfiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/dbwu4w7w/

Answer (score 0):

That is one of the nicest forms i have ever come accross:-)

```
  <ul class="slideshow">
        <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
        <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
        <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
        <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
        <li><span>Image 05</span></li>
        <li><span>Image 06</span></li>
    </ul>
```

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/GpyPMa

I am not sure i understood the question, but check it out and let me know.

Comment: Thanks! That means a lot I only started making websites the other week with barely any coding experience :o this didn't fix it though, in the end I went a different direction let me know what you think! http://codepen.io/MJSBLUES/pen/xwpyvG

Comment: You are welcome, btw, something is off with the codepen, Try to put the compiled css there, no need for stylesheet and head section on codepen.
Does this (classList.add) actually work with jquery?:-)
Explain please, what do you want the form to do/look like?